# Conversion String to NSDate - Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, string, nsdate

What is wrong?
The same code works on other classes. When I convert the string to a nsdate the simulator crashes.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd/MM/yyyy (HH:mm)"
        
        
        //ordino il file 
        var dataminima = dateFormatter.date(from: "lun, 01/01/2010 (01:01)")
        var datamassima = dateFormatter.date(from: "lun, 01/01/2010 (01:01)")
        
        var indice = 0
        var indiceminimo = 1
        
        var indice1 = 0
        
        for data in arraycomplessivo {
            let validData = data as! NSDictionary
            let dataestratta = validData["data"]
            print(dataestratta as! String)
            
            //converto da stringa a NSDate - that's the error
            let dataconvertita = dateFormatter.date(from:dataestratta as! String)!
            
            //print(dataminima!)
            print(dataconvertita)
```

**// dataestratta is: gio, 10/06/2021 (12:00)**

[image]

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIIjP.png)

Comment: Why use `NSDictionary`, rather than `Dictionary`? Also same goes with `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: What is the output of `print(dataestratta as! String)`? You are using too many exclamation marks, that's an invitation "please crash me". And don't use `NSDictionary/NSArray` in Swift.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed it. I just edit the post.
dataestratta is:
gio, 10/06/2021 (12:00)

That's correct with the date format "EEE, dd/MM/yyyy (HH:mm)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locale in the Simulator is not necessarily the same as on your device or your Mac.

As the string date format is obviously Italian add a fixed locale

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd/MM/yyyy (HH:mm)"
```